# Is it possible to preserve the uploaded file in input type="file" tag

Tags: html, retain, server-side-scripting, preserve

I am using `<input type="file" name="upload_file" >` inside a form on submitting I am using a post action , where it processes all the form fields , suppose when it encounts an error and returns to the original form itself . Is it possible to preserve the selected file by the user rather than asking the user to again click browse and select the file .

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Comment: Ruby on Rails , but I also want to know in general is it possible

Comment: hmm it's not possible in my opinion your file data will reset when refreshed. What I can suggest is put your validation in js and don't submit the form if there are errors in your input. Then shoot the form if all are valid

Answer (score 0):

You could use client-side validations for the form fields, that way you can keep the uploaded file.